# How can I prove this relationship between the S-matrix and the Gamma matrices?

Tags: quantum-field-theory, operators, lorentz-symmetry

For an infinitesimal Lorentz transformation:

$$
S(\Lambda)=1+i\epsilon_{\rho\sigma}s^{\rho\sigma}
$$
$$
S(\Lambda)^{-1}=1-i\epsilon_{\rho\sigma}s^{\rho\sigma}
$$

and apparently if we just plug that into

$$
\Lambda^\mu_\nu\gamma^\nu=S(\Lambda)^{-1}\gamma^\mu S(\Lambda)
$$

we should be able to prove that:

$$
s^{\rho\sigma}=\frac{i}{4}[\gamma^\rho,\gamma^\sigma]=\frac{i}{2}(\gamma^\rho\gamma^\sigma-\eta^{\rho\sigma})
$$

considering that:

$$
\Lambda^\mu_\nu = \delta^\mu_\nu-\epsilon_{\rho\sigma}(g^{\rho\mu}\delta^\sigma_\nu-g^{\sigma\mu}\delta^\rho_\nu)
$$

I tried to do it and I got to this expression:

$$
s^{\rho\sigma}\delta^\mu_ \nu=i(g^{\sigma\mu}\gamma^\rho-g^{\rho\mu}\gamma^\sigma)
$$

but after that I'm stuck, I've tried a bunch of different things but nothing works.

Also, I'm a little confused about the $g$s and $\eta$s, I argued that since the expression is a scalar, on account of the repeated indices, it will be the same in any coordinate system, so $g$ might as well be $\eta$, but I'm not sure if that's actually correct.

Also, having 3 indices instead of 2 seems very problematic but I don't know how to get rid of them.

Comment: You shouldn't call this thing the "S-matrix", that S is reserved for "scattering".

Comment: be careful with your index contractions: you can't have 4 free indices on one side of the equation and 3 on the other, they should match if you apply the rules of tensor calculus correctly

Comment: also $\epsilon_{\mu\nu}$ is reserved for the levi-civitta symbol. The conventional notation is $\omega_{\mu\nu}$

Comment: “Relation between S-matrix and gamma matrices” is a clickbait :)